# Explicit nunit tests not running when selected by category

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm having a subset of tests that are annotated by `[explicit]` and `[category("SmokeTest")` for example:

```cs
[TestFixture]
[Explicit]
[Category("SmokeTest")]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
class V631SmokeTests
{
  [Test]
  public void V631WithAllOptions1250WidthMeasuringAndBasicTransportSystem()
  {
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
  }
}
```

When developing in VS I can explicitly start the tests and they run. However on the build agent I'm running into trouble. All `[Explicit]` tests are skipped while I did specify a category (to my understanding that should overrule the explicit annotation).

After compiling all code successfully in a previous step and the command:
`dotnet test project.sln --test-adapter-path:. --no-build --no-restore -f net472 -v:m --filter TestCategory=SmokeTest -l "console;verbosity=normal"` I get the output that the test is skipped

```
V631WithAllOptions1250WidthMeasuringAndBasicTransportSystem: OneTimeSetUp:
Skipped V631WithAllOptions1250WidthMeasuringAndBasicTransportSystem [2 ms]
```

Most likely I'm overlooking something as I have gotten things like this to work in the past. But I'm just not seeing it this time.

**versions**

- Nunit: 3.13.3
- Nunit3TestAdapter: 4.2.1
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk: 17.3.2

Comment: _to my understanding that should overrule the explicit annotation_ → do you have this from the official docs or is it your expectation? Because for me it feels natural that `Explicit` is stronger than `Category` and therefore wins.

Comment: I followed the [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=nunit) my guess is that `--filter` is a pass trough to `--where` what should set a filter to select tests. then [looking in the Nunit documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/explicit.html) it states 'The test or fixture will be run if it is selected by name or if it is included by use of a filter.' By that I'm guessing that `Category` overrules `Explicit` but I could be wrong. In that case my question would be: How do I run `explicit` tests

Comment: By _explicitly_ selecting either the single test (`V631WithAllOptions1250WidthMeasuringAndBasicTransportSystem`) or the test class (`V631SmokeTests`) - whatever is marked as `Explicit`

Comment: That remains confusing to me. The Nuget doc literally states a category as valid selection in the examples. I just tried it with stripping away `dotnet test` and using the nunit console runner and then the command behaves as I had expected. I was hoping to get the same functionality via dotnet test as I could get rid of the additional tool.

Comment: Use `dotnet test --filter V631SmokeTests` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=nunit)). This works nicely for me